# Python3 and GTK3 on Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pygtk, gtk3

I am currently trying to use GTK3 and Python3 for GUI development.

Everything is working fine while doing this on my Ubuntu device, but as I want to be able to have Windows executables later, I need to set these tools up on Windows 7.

I have Python 3.4.4 (64 Bit) installed on my system and tried solutions from other posts on Stackoverflow to be able to use GTK with it, but I was not able to get it to work.

When trying to import Gtk (`import gi` and `from gi.repository import Gtk`) on the Python shell, the following error occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2158, in _find_spec
AttributeError: 'DynamicImporter' object has no attribute 'find_spec'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\gi\importer.py", line 100, in find_module
    'introspection typelib not found' % namespace)
ImportError: cannot import name Gtk, introspection typelib not found
```

What I have installed at the moment:

- [PyGi 3.18.2 AIO for Python 3.4 64-bit](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/files/)
- [GTK3-Runtime Win64](https://github.com/tschoonj/GTK-for-Windows-Runtime-Environment-Installer) (`bin` directory created during installation is included into PATH)

Which is the best way to get a working set of Python3 and GTK3 on Windows? (As far as I have seen it is not possible to create Windows executables using Ubuntu.)

Comment: Please post the and the codes that brings this error for debugging simplification

Comment: @ArduinoSentinel The code is already included into my post (see the paragraph above the error message).

Comment: @oldtechaa The link on the GNOME PyGObject page leads me to the Sourceforge project page I already mentioned inside my post, but does not seem to work.

Comment: Sorry, totally missed that. I'll retract my flag if it hasn't already been rejected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need only to install Python 3.4 and the PyGObject project on sourceforge (the one you mentioned in your post).
This setup *must* work on Windows, because it works for me.

Maybe you missed to check the Gtk3 libraries during installation of PyGObject (this is a frequent error).

You don't need msys2 at all to use PyGObject in Python.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that this is not selected by default and you have to pay attention to this when scrolling through the long list. Not it works.

Comment: Let's try to uninstall and install again Python and PyGObject.

Comment: Sorry, missed the right key on my keyboard. Should be "Now it works" ;)

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this info. I was getting annoyed that I couldnt just install the GTK3 libraries in the python installation dir and worried that I could only run those apps via msys32 terminal... not to mention all the unnecessary extra files for msys2. Most instructions for windows lead you directly to the msys installer... trap for newbies